# Why does converting a disk to GPT with diskpart automatically create a 128MB reserved partion?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, gpt, diskpart, disk-management

I recently bought a 3TB internal HDD, intended to be used as a backup drive to encompass all of my data. After installing the drive into my system, I started to use Windows' command-line `diskpart` tool to initialise it, as part of which it needed converting to a GPT disk. Eventually after some experimenting, I realised that doing so, using:

```
convert GPT
```

...automatically creates a 128MB reserved partition on the disk:

[image]

Why does `diskpart` create this partition, and if I'm planning to use this disk purely as a data drive (as opposed to a boot drive), can I safely delete the reserved partition to create one primary partition encompassing the entire drive?

Comment: It's already been answered:
https://superuser.com/questions/654798/are-gpt-reserved-and-efi-system-partitions-important

Comment: @FilippoTarpini For boot drives, yes. It says nothing about what the GPT partition does on a non-boot (i.e. data only) drive and whether it's safe to delete it on one, as asked in the body of my question.

Answer (score 3):

> "A Microsoft Reserved Partition is only created when a drive formatted in a Globally Unique IDentifier or GUID partition table (GPT) format and when the BIOS is set for Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI)."

[Source](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln288535/what-is-the-128mb-partition-that-is-created-during-the-installation-of-windows-)

Comment: The question was *why* is it created and can you get rid of it.  Simply stating that it gets created does not answer the question.

Comment: That source partially answers the question of why, i.e. as part of a Windows installation on a GPT drive, but it doesn't address the question of why it is created for a standard data drive or whether it's needed on one.

Comment: @psusi this is the question "Why does converting a disk to GPT with diskpart automatically create a 128MB reserved partion?" Getting rid of it would be a duplicate question.

Comment: @Moab That's the title of the question because it can't contain the whole question - the rest of the question is in the body, and isn't a duplicate of any other, because no other question asks the same; whether deleting the reserved partition created by `convert GPT` can be safely deleted for a data drive.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the question, but valuable information for anyone coming across this and wanting to know how to delete the partition, which is protected by default.

#### To delete the 128MB reserved partition

Type the following commands one at a time in the command-line:

`diskpart`

`list partition`

`select partition 1`

`delete partition override`

#### To create a new primary partition encompassing the entire drive and mount it:

`create partition primary`

`format fs=ntfs quick`<sup>1</sup>

`assign letter=D`<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>**1** Replace `ntfs` with the filesystem you want to format the disk with, and remove `quick` if you want to perform a full format</sup>
<sup>**2** Replace `D` with the volume label that you want the drive to be mounted on, or simply use `assign` to mount the drive with a random unused label</sup>

Answer (score 0):

[Are GPT reserved and EFI system partitions important?](https://superuser.com/questions/654798/are-gpt-reserved-and-efi-system-partitions-important)
says Windows just allocates an empty, unused, partition just in case it might need it for something later on. It's safe to delete, I just did for all my drives.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1084021)

Comment: It does answer that exact question. Windows creates a reserved partition for both Boot and Data drives, and it's safe to delete, as it's not used by default.