# Which, if any, of these partitions on my HD can I, should I eliminate or "shrink"? And, what temp is good?

Tags: partitioning, high-definition

I just ran CrystalDiskInfo and can see the (I THINK) relatively unused 29GB partition that I KNEW was there (saw it in File Explorer, with Adobe_Reader, VeriFace and YouCam on it)...but there appear to be two MORE partitions that I wasn't aware of and have no idea what/why they are.

Any tips on whether I should "mess" with ANY of these?

Also, is the 39 deg temp of my drive OK? Or is that a little warm?

[image]

Comment: Without a screenshot of disk management we cannot advise on partitions, make and model of PC also.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are GPT reserved and EFI system partitions important?](https://superuser.com/questions/654798/are-gpt-reserved-and-efi-system-partitions-important)

Comment: With the partitioning as it is there isn't much you can do. Your D: drive and the partition behind it are likely recovery partitions. If you do have actual storage issues get an external drive or check whenever you can add a second HDD.

Comment: @gronostaj This PC has BIOS, not UEFI, so it's MBR

Answer (score 0):

**Partitions:**

- **1: Boot** [primary] partition (200MB)
- **3: OEM Recovery** [extended] partition (14.75GB)
- **4:** *[Likely]* **OEM Tools** [logical] partition of #3 (29GB)

  - *Generally speaking, an OEM tools partition doesn't have a drive letter assigned to it, so it's likely this was either done manually or via a Windows Update/Repair Install that forgot to unmount that partition*

To answer your question:

- Partitions 3 & 4 can be removed

  - I would recommend capturing a WIM image of both of them prior to removal

    - *See **Commands** section of [this](https://superuser.com/a/1503102/529800) answer*
  - Once removed, you'll want to [move WinRE](https://superuser.com/a/1514869/529800) *(**Win**dows **R**ecovery **E**nvironment)* to its own partition.
- Or the `C:` partition can be shrunk and a last primary partition created *(max for BIOS PCs is 4)*

HDD temp is fine and would only be of concern if it's continually >45C when not under load, which would signify an airflow/cooling issue.